# Grails - Unable to execute SELECT WHERE with Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, grails, groovy

I am attempting to execute a SELECT WHERE query in grails to implement a login page. I am not supposed to use PHP or Spring for data validation.

**user.groovy**

package loginmysql

```
class User {

    String userName
    String password

    static constraints = {
        userName (unique:true)
        password (password:true)
    }
}
```

**userController.groovy**

```
package loginmysql

class UserController {

    def UserService

    def index() {
    UserService.createTables();
    //UserService.insertToTables() // upon Inserting, must not be inserted twice
}

def login() {
    UserService.searchLoginInput(params.userName,params.password)
    redirect(action: "index")   // return to index page again and display login message*/
}

}
```

**userService.groovy**

```
package loginmysql

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import groovy.sql.Sql

@Transactional
class UserService {

    def dataSource

    def searchLoginInput(String input_user, String input_pass) {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def sql2 = new Sql(dataSource)
        int userNum = 0
        sql.eachRow('SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userName=$input_user') { row ->
            if (input_user == row.userName) {
                sql2.eachRow('SELECT password FROM users WHERE password=$input_pass') { row2 ->
                    if (input_pass == row2.password) {
                        flash.message = " login succeded!!!"
                        session.user = input_user   // keep info on who connected
                        userNum++
                    } else {
                        flash.message = "login failed!!!"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (userNum==0) flash.message = "Username not found!!!"
    }

    def createTables(){
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.execute '''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            userId INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
            userName VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
            password VARCHAR(100)
            )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
            '''
    }

    def insertToTables(){
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def params = ['vagg77', 'pass']
        sql.execute 'INSERT INTO users (userName, password) VALUES (?, ?)', params
        params = ['mary', 'pass']
        sql.execute 'INSERT INTO users (userName, password) VALUES (?, ?)', params
    }
}
```

Here is what happens at the page login:

[image]

If I add a println() function inside searchLoginInput(), then I see that the values are correctly sent from my Controller to my Service

[image]

This is the exact error I have:

[image]

I was wondering If the query I entered was had wrong syntax at MySQL so I attempted to execute the query at a mysql console.

**Database Entries**

[image]

**MySQL Query in console**

[image]

Comment: GStrings use double quotes, not single quotes. So it should be `sql.eachRow("SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userName=${input_user}").` Also note the use of curly braces too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable substitution in Groovy String (or GStrings) requires you to use double quotes, not single quotes. Plus, the use of curly braces.

So, in your case creating your SQL statements would look something like this:

`"SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userName=${input_user}"`

Comment: thanks for the heads up, as you can see from the poorly formatted code, I am a total beginner at grails. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: "However, as a side note. You shouldn't be creating SQL statements like this.  You are opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks by doing so." - I don't think that is true.  The `Sql` class intercepts that property access and does the appropriate escaping.

Comment: This is done by having an overloaded version of methods like `eachRow` that accepts a `GString` as an argument so the string does not get interpolated before being passed as an arg.  See https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/473bd1a6524781229a93c9233a622d7a1bec96de/subprojects/groovy-sql/src/main/java/groovy/sql/Sql.java#L1553.  From there, the individual parameter values are pulled out of the `GString`, the rest of the string value is retrieved from the `GString` and eventually a `PreparedStatement` is created and populated with parameters so the whole thing is SQL injection safe.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, as always, thank you. For this, and so much else too!

Comment: No problem.  It is a great feature.

Answer (score 0):

Why use SQL instead of Gorm? 
If you want to change the query you only have to use this:

```
User.findByUsername(input_user)
```

Comment: I am instructed to use sql queries, injected with a datasource instead of GORM :P

Comment: Ok, but if you are a beginner at Grails you should know that working with sql queries instead GORM is a bad idea. Unless you need to work with stored procedure, you should use Grails criterias.

Comment: "...you should know that working with sql queries instead GORM is a bad idea." - That is not always true.  There are good reasons to use SQL.  GORM (and ORM in general) is not always the best solution for every scenario.  There are times when SQL is perfectly justified.

Comment: Yes of course, but in general you don't need to write SQL unless you need to run something like stored procedure or too specific.
Sorry for my bad english :/

Comment: "Yes of course, but in general you don't need to write SQL unless you need to run something like stored procedure or too specific." - In general, that is reasonable but there are reasons other than stored procedures that SQL might make more sense than using ORM.  I was addressing the claim "...you should know that working with sql queries instead GORM is a bad idea".